# How To get to 'me' Json in Facebook c# SDK with WP7 and silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

im new at the Facebook C# SDK and im trying to do somthing for windows phone 7 but helf of the function are restricted to silverlight cuz 'Silverlight should only have async calls', im really trying to do this:

```
// Using IDictionary<string, object> (.Net 3.5, .Net 4.0, WP7)
var client = new FacebookClient();
var me = (IDicationary<string,object>)client.Get("me");
string firstName = (string)me["first_name"];
string lastName = (string)me["last_name"];
string email = (string)me["email"];
```

as in: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation

but i cant use the get method...
ill explain my self better!, i want to save the info, there is a solution out there:

```
_fbClient.GetCompleted +=
    (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MyData.ItemsSource = result);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
    };
_fbClient.GetAsync("/me");
```

problem is there is no way to access the MyData.ItemsSource, i need to access each field or ask for each field by it self...  any thoughts?

this guy might have some direction:
http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Batch-Requests.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
var fname = (string)result["first_name"];
var lname = (string)result["last_name"];
```

If it is a json object cast it to IDictionary<string,object>, if array cast it to IList<object>. if string cast it to string, if numbers cast it to double and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the Silverlight sample:

```
    fb.GetCompleted +=
    (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => InfoBox.ItemsSource = result);
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Need to let the user know there was an error
        }
    };

    fb.GetAsync("/me");
```

Comment: but this doesn't solve the field by field issue, how do i reach each field?

Comment: You should be able to access them through the result object.  Try doing it the same way you did in your original example.